# How to introduce the infinity in the Tropical Arithmetic using Z3

Tags: z3

The following code introduces the basic properties of the Tropical Arithmetic using Z3 with SMT-LIB:

```
; This example illustrates basic tropical arithmetic 

(define-fun tropadd  ((a Real)(b Real)) Real (if (> a b)
                                        b
                                        a))
(define-fun tropmul ((a Real)(b Real)) Real (+ a b))
(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun y () Real)
(declare-fun z () Real)
(push)
(assert(not(= (tropadd x y) (tropadd y x))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
(push)
(assert(not(= (tropmul x y) (tropmul y x))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
(push)
(assert(not(= (tropmul x (tropmul y z)) (tropmul (tropmul x y) z))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
(push)
(assert(not(= (tropadd x (tropadd y z)) (tropadd (tropadd x y) z))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
(push)
(assert(not(= (tropmul x (tropadd y z)) (tropadd (tropmul x y) (tropmul x z)))))
(check-sat)
(pop)

(push)
(assert(not(= (tropmul x 0) x)))
(check-sat)
(pop)
(push)
(assert (= (tropmul x 2) 3))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(pop)
(push)
(assert (= (tropadd x 2) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The output is:

```
unsat 
unsat 
unsat 
unsat 
unsat 
unsat 

sat 
(model (define-fun x () Real 1.0) 

sat 
(model (define-fun x () Real 1.0) )
```

Please run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/7oGF)

This code introduces the tropical addition and the tropical multiplication.   Then is proved that these operations satisfy:  commutative, associate, distributive; and modulative for the tropical multiplication.

With the aim to satisfy the modulative for the tropical addition is necessary to introduce 
the infinity, it is to say a new symbol such: infinity + *a* = *a* for all *a*.

Please, can you teach me how to introduce such infinity in the tropical code.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to define a new type, some sort of a discriminating union to include the infinity; and extend your operations to cover this new type. The standard way to do this in SMT-Lib is to introduce an uninterpreted sort, and then assert the definitions of mul/add etc., as appropriate axioms over it. How well the underlying solver will handle such axioms really will depend on how well it handles quantifiers and what sort of problems you throw at it, since those axioms will no doubt involve quantifiers.

An alternative is to use a higher-level approach, such as advocated by Z3Py or SBV (Haskell bindings to Z3 and other SMT solvers), where you can hide most of the machinery in the high-level structure as afforded by those languages. That's what I would try first, as SMT-Lib can get quite verbose and error-prone when you deal with a lot of uninterpreted sorts, axioms, etc.